# In HTML with CSS -- using "float" to position images in a single row

Tags: html, css

In a web page I would like to have three images at the top, all in the same row, spaced so that the first one is all the way left and the other two are next to each other in the center of the page.  Here is how I visualize the code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" style="float:left;">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/101/100" style="float:center;">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/101" style="float:center;">
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It doesn't work like this and I'm hoping someone can tell me how to make it happen.  Thank you very much!

Comment: `float:center` doesn't exist.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float. But by default, `th` already has `text-align:center`, so you don't need to do anything to center the centered elements; just float the one element that needs to float left.  (Reminder the table needs to have a width set, otherwise it'll collapse to fit the contents)

Comment: A) Don't use tables for layout. Use tables for tabular data. B) Try flexbox for your layout

Comment: @j08691 aggreed - unless coding for e.g. email....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, `<table>` is not meant to be used for creating interfaces, but tabular data. Just use a normal `<div>` or whatever deem to fit.

Also, `float` is fine, but modern approaches are often preferred to it when it comes to element positioning.

A possible solution to your problem is grid. An overview of the basic concepts can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Basic_concepts_of_grid_layout) (and for flexbox, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox)).

```css
#grid {
  /* Create a grid... */
  display: grid;
  /*
    ...with 3 columns, of which
    the two outermost are of equal width.
  */ 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.item {
  /* Make the two images in the second column fit nicely. */
  display: flex;
}

/* Demo only */

#grid {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/102/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/101/100">
  </div>
</div>
```